# How can I create a box shadow in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I create the box shadow attached in android using kotlin?

Also how to I change the background of my application to white?

[image]

Comment: What you have done? anything?

Comment: Please visit: https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping I hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

You can try below ways

1. Use `CardView` : Use this `ImageView` inside the `Cardview` and give `cardElevation`. In this you can also give round corner by giving `cornerRadius`
2. Use `Drawable` background : You can give background of `ImageView`

`imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shadow_drawable);`

or

`android:background="@drawable/shadow_drawable";`

**shadow_drawable**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:top="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="#00CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:top="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:top="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:top="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:top="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Hope, it will help